# Mostrar mensagem de "Aguarde..." enquando a página carrega por completo - MVC jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho uma `view` que carrega um [DataTable.Net](http://www.datatables.net/), onde preciso exibir um PopUp com a mensagem "`Aguarde...`".

O PopUp abre quando a página é carregada, mas como faço para fechá-lo? Do jeito que eu fiz, o PopUp não fecha, o que está errado? Existe algum outro modo mais eficiente de se fazer isso?

> obs.: Depois vou replicar esse PopUp para ser usada nas demais `View`'s.

Segue-se o código abaixo daquilo que eu já tenho até agora:

```
<style type="text/css">
.progresso {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 360px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
}
</style>
.
//AQUI O HTML É CARREGADO
.

<div id="divCarregando" class="progresso"> 
    <img src="~/Imagens/midi.gif" />
    <br /> Carregando... 
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

    $("#divCarregando").show();
    .
    .
    .
    $("#divCarregando").show('hide');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método correto seria - `.hide();` e não `.show('hide');`. O PopUp não está a funcionar porque basicamente estás a dizer-lhe para ele abrir, e logo de seguida fechar com o `.hide();`.

Para fechar o PopUp após a página estar totalmente carregada, utiliza o `$(window).load(function ()`, juntamente com um `fadeOut()` apontando para o `id` pretendido. Isto vai fazer com que o elemento `#divCarregando` não desapareça repentinamente, mas sim dissolvendo-se até desaparecer por completo quando a página estiver totalmente carregada.

Eis um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divCarregando").show();
    $(window).load(function () {
        // Quando a página estiver totalmente carregada, remove o id
        $('#divCarregando').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.progresso {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divCarregando" class="progresso">
    <p>Aguarde...</p>
</div>
```

Aproveitei também e fiz algumas alterações no teu código CSS para centralizar melhor essa "caixa do modal".

Comment: perfeito! obrigado!

Comment: Chun do jeito que está já atende minhas necessidades, mas digamos que o tempo de carregamento da página pode variar, em um determinado período do dia 1 segundo e outro período 3 segundos, então como trabalhar com essa variação de tempo ? Sem fixar o tempo de que o popup fica aberto ?

Comment: Tens razão @AdrianoCordeiro , eu é que não pensei nisso na altura. Editei agora a minha resposta, agora está da maneira correta, para desaparecer apenas quando a página estiver totalmente carregada.

Comment: Show de bola! Funfa perfeitamente. \o/